# Conditional probability question about a r.v with geometric distribution

Tags: probability

I'm going through my textbook for a measure theory and probability course I'm following at uni. I have encountered this problem that seems logical in nature, but I'm not sure I'm proficient enough at handling r.v's that I can solve it. The problem is,

For a r.v with geometric distribution and for $i,j>0$ show that,

$P(x>i+j\vert x>i)=P(x>j)$

It seems logical when putting the problem into words, but when I try to calculate it,

$P(x>i+j\vert x>i)=\frac{P(\{X>i+j\}\cap\{X>i\})}{P(X>i)}=\frac{P(\{X>i+j\})}{P(X>i)}$

and I hit a dead end. I have tried using their probabilities written as sums directly, but that doesn't seem to yield any result for me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(x>i)=\sum\limits_{k=i+1}^{\infty} p((1-p)^{k}=p\frac {(1-p)^{i+1} } {1-(1-p)}$ by the formula for a  geometric sum. This gives $P(x>i)=(1-p)^{i+1}$. Can you finish?

Comment: I'm guessing now it's because $P(x>i+j)=(1-p)^{i+j+1}$ which leads to $\frac{P(x>i+j)}{P(x>i)}=\frac{(1-p)^{j+i+1}}{(1-p)^{i+1}}=(1-p)^{j+1}=P(x>j)$.

Comment: @NoviceSprinter Yes, you have competed the proof now.

Comment: Thank you very much!